# Add EZAudio to project without Podfile

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, cocoapods

I'm trying to implement an Db meter into an existing Phonegap app. To solve this task for iOS I'm want to add [this Objective-C code](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/building-an-audio-meter-using-shinobigauges) to my project. It works fine in XCode but I have no idea how to get the EZAudio Framework into my PG app without the Podfile. Is it possible to just copy all the files in /Pods/EZAudio? What's the recommended way? I'm quite a noob to the Obj-C world so any help is appreciated!

Comment: do you want to create a plugin or just use it in your project?

Comment: it's not a real plugin - i want to create a plugin out of the code in the link! do you have an idea?

Comment: According to the readme, you can just drag the whole folder to your xcode project

Answer (score 0):

A simple method consists in letting `pod install` do the hard work and create a consistent version of all **Pods**, move out what you need, then fix your `Podfile` and execute a new `rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock ; pod install` on a closed workspace.

The **Pods** directory is located at the same level as your **Xcode** project.
You are free to move them in the location of your choice, and import these files into your project.

In your example, you will need to refer to both `EZAudio` and `TPCircularBuffer`.
Of course, not using the **Podfile** or `pod install` has its drawback, such as maintaining coherent versions of libraries, which is one issue `CocoaPods` specifically addresses.